# Why is there a TextBox instead of a Button in Data Explorer's Captcha?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, design, captcha

I was trying to run a query in Data Explorer without logging in (I didn't notice that I am not logged in). When I click on <kbd>Run Query</kbd> button, I got a Captcha to avoid spam queries. But what I found that there is a Textbox instead of a Button for *I'm a Human Being*.

[image]

The Textbox is not ideal option for that. So there should be a button instead of Textbox like this one:

[image]

Comment: Whatever, robot.

Comment: Is that *actually* a textbox, or is it a button that just *looks like* a textbox?

Comment: @Gaffi: The "Ask Question" button on this page is just a link: `<a id="nav-askquestion"  href="/questions/ask">Ask Question</a>`, inside a `<div><ul>`.  I would imagine the Captcha "button" is something similar.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right, well I suppose that's my point: It's not a field into which you can enter data, however much it may appear to be.

Comment: I say change it to a button, but configure it to look like a textbox.

Comment: @Nick it's not completed, the site was never updated.

Comment: I don't understand why some people disagree with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149328/why-there-is-a-textbox-instead-of-button-in-data-explorers-captcha/149331#149331), the problem was simply bad markup - a trailing quote was missing on the `style` attribute. Apparently it's been this way for at least 17 months, so I'm amazed that this is the first time anyone's noticed.

At any rate, I've fixed it now. Will be deployed in the next build (> 2012.9.7.6).

Comment: I think everyone noticed. It still functioned as a button though so...

Comment: True, but it would have been a prime target for an "Eeeek! You got your text box in my button!" post.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169914/152859) it's still not fixed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There hasn't been a new build yet

Comment: Oh my... so is it updated once a year??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, but it's lower priority than the other stuff Nick has been working on (I have no control over the builds). I'll ask him if he has some time to look into it next week.

Answer (score 10):

It is supposed to be a button. The markup is just screwed up.

```
<input id="btn-captcha" style="font-weight:bold; type=" button"="" name="submit-captcha" value="&nbsp;I'm a Human Being&nbsp;" placeholder="UNKNOWN_TYPE">
```

Should be:

```
<input id="btn-captcha" style="font-weight:bold;" type="button" name="submit-captcha" value="&nbsp;I'm a Human Being&nbsp;" placeholder="UNKNOWN_TYPE">
```

Answer (score 0):

I see markup problems as well, but not exactly the same ones as GEOCHET is getting.

Internet Explorer 8:

```
<input id="btn-captcha" style="font-weight:bold; type="button" name="submit-captcha" value="&nbsp;I'm a Human Being&nbsp;"/>
```

There's a missing quotation mark after `bold;`.

Firefox 10:

```
<input value=" I'm a Human Being " name="submit-captcha" button"="" style="font-weight:bold; type=" id="btn-captcha">
```

Not only is there a missing quotation mark after `bold;`, there's weirdness surrounding `button` and `type`. These are the same errors as GEOCHET's, but in a different order.