# Maybe it's time to update the code base of Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Not talking about the data, this one appears to be updating regularly which is awesome.

Talking about this:

> [image]

There is outdated footer (e.g. "contact us" is still a `mailto:` link!) and [more than a few open bug reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer+bug+-status-completed+-status-bydesign) that Tim fixed and the fix was never pushed to production.

Comment: Yes please. It makes confusions. Some bugs which are solved and tagged with `Status-Completed` are actually solved from their end. But users think it is not resolved yet. (Obviously if someone see a [bug report as `Status-Completed`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149328/187824) and it is not implemented yet he will post [another question like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169914/187824))

Comment: [YES](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuil596dg98u4eu/Photo%20Jan%2001%2C%203%2026%2041%20PM.jpg)

Comment: [Darn it, I made a fancy image then I realized you were talking about data.SE :P](http://i.imgur.com/imbzQsC.png) At least I got to practice my freehand red skills for later use :D

Comment: @Doorknob happens to the best of us... +1 for the freehand circles! :)

Comment: Surely it will be updated within 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And finally it's updated, with [bunch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158952/152859) of [bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149328/152859) fixed!

[image]

Footer is still the old design but guess we can live with that.

(The dev who did it is more than welcome to post, but better have some sort of answer until then)

Comment: It was updated the other day when [SEDE moved to NY](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/357547343505129472), and then again to incorporate the new help page. The footer will be changed in the next(ish) deploy.

Comment: @Tim took them 10 months to update so the "footer will be changed in the next(ish) deploy" might take 10 more months - well, no rush! :)

Comment: @Sha - Oh I just noticed this today.

Comment: @hims056 cheers, thanks for [the badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=152859)!

Answer (score 7):

We do intend to update it again... but unfortunately I can't give you an ETA beyond the usual "6-8 weeks".

There are a lot of changes that we haven't had a chance to review and while [we trust Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180896/why-did-i-get-associated-as-jon-doe/180897?noredirect=1#comment549361_180897), we want to be sure before merging and deploying anything.

I'm keeping this in the back of my mind, though, and I'm checking with the devs periodically to see if anything changes.

Comment: Should remind Nick about switching to GitHub going forward too, it would make pulling smaller chunks much easier.

Comment: Wow, 8 minutes left you're lucky! Anyway thanks a bunch, that's fair enough for now.