# Why did I get associated as Jon Doe?

Tags: support, data-explorer

When I logged into Stack Exchange Data Explorer for the first time today using my normal Stack Exchange Open ID I was given the display name Jon.Doe8551.  There are indeed [66 pages](https://data.stackexchange.com/users?order_by=all&search=jon.doe&page=1) of Jon.Does on SEDE, why is that?

Comment: @ben not a dupe, this one was caused by duplicate display name as Rory explained below. On second thought maybe it's better to close as dupe but add another answer there?

Comment: I don't suppose it matters @Sha, whatever the reason I think it's answered there, this question has _"logged into Stack Exchange Data Explorer for the first time today"_ and Waffles answered _"As it stands data.se tries to guess a login for you from your openid provider, if it fails it assigns you a unique jon.doe login."_ The fact that the OP tried to change their display name seems irrelevant? Or possibly I'm being stupid (wouldn't surprise me).

Comment: @ben the login was correct, but something else failed (e.g. "duplicate key isn't allowed" .NET error) which caused the fallback to default name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When attempting to change my display name on the site, I was presented with an error stating that on the Data Explorer all usernames need to be unique.  I assume that everyone who attempts to associate with a  username that is already in the system is assigned the next available Jon Doe name.

Comment: I have no idea why this is, actually. I'll look into removing the requirement if there doesn't seem to be a good reason for it.

Comment: @Tim good intention, but keep in mind that even if you fix it, long months (years?) might pass before the fix is deployed. I start to believe the team has abandoned Data Explorer altogether from the complete lack of response.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, I'm slightly more optimistic than that :P

Comment: @TimStone your judgement is simply clouded by your recent increase in status. Those moderator privileges might simply have induced a power trip. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There are a lot of changes waiting in the Data Explorer repo at this point and we simply haven't had the time to go through and vet them. I keep asking Nick about it periodically, but he's been busy with other work.

Comment: @Anna I was under the impression that Tim already made all the changes and only need a dev to push a button... didn't know it requires more dev time than that. Thanks, maybe it's worth adding as answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178288/152859)? Not too late to get the bounty! :-)

Comment: @Anna What, you don't trust me? ;) (As an aside, a large portion of the pending changes don't impact the hosted SEDE)